Existence/simplification of $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\ln(1-e^{-\sqrt{x^2+a^2}})}{x^2-b^2}}$
I am reading a paper where the following integral is shown: 
where $\omega=\sqrt{(p^2+m_{phi}^2)}$
When trying to compute it numerically, it seems like MATLAB was having trouble with the poles. I used desmos to see if the integral actually diverges but saw that if I took the principle value at the discontinuities it looked like it could converge. After some rewriting I see the two parts with $L_1$ and $L_2$ can be written in the form
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\ln(1-e^{-\sqrt{x^2+a^2}})}{x^2-b^2}}$$.
This form makes me a little skeptical since it's not obvious if even its principle value exists. I've went over my work several times and it looks like integrals of this form will appear when integrating by parts so I will assume it does exist (which I could be wrong about). Now, I am a loss for what "tricks" I can use to make this any nicer. I am wondering if there is some divine closed form solution for this, or if there is some way to rewrite the integral to exclude to singularities (like rewriting $\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{\ln(u)}du$ as $li(2)+\int_{2}^{x} \frac{1}{\ln(u)}du$)

Maybe this can help....

@whatamidoing big issue is the 1/(z^2-a^2). not sure how to handle integrals of the form $\frac{e^{-\sqrt(z^+b^2)}}{(z^2-a^2)}$
